# discord-giveaways | TypeError: Cannot read property 'start' of undefined

Tags: javascript, discord.js, command, bots, undefined

**Giveaway.js**

I am getting this error, and I don't know how to fix it, but tutorials use the same thing and don't get this error.:

> "Cannot read property 'start' of undefined"

```
   client.giveawaysManager.start(giveawayChannel, {
            // The giveaway duration
            time: ms(giveawayDuration),
            // The giveaway prize
            prize: giveawayPrize,
            // The giveaway winner count
            winnerCount: giveawayNumberWinners,
            // Who hosts this giveaway
            hostedBy: client.config.hostedBy ? message.author : null,
            // Messages
            messages: {
                giveaway: (client.config.everyoneMention ? "@everyone\n\n" : "")+ client.config.giveawayEmoji + "**GIVEAWAY**" + client.config.giveawayEmoji,
                giveawayEnded: (client.config.everyoneMention ? "@everyone\n\n" : "")+ client.config.giveawayEmoji + "**GIVEAWAY ENDED**" + client.config.giveawayEmoji,
                timeRemaining: "Time remaining: **{duration}**!",
                inviteToParticipate: "React with " + client.config.giveawayEmoji + " to participate!",
                winMessage: client.config.giveawayEmoji + " {winners} won **{prize}**!",
                embedFooter: client.config.botName,
                noWinner: "Giveaway cancelled, no valid participations.",
                hostedBy: "Hosted by: {user}",
                winners: "winner(s)",
                endedAt: "Ended at",
                units: {
                    seconds: "seconds",
                    minutes: "minutes",
                    hours: "hours",
                    days: "days",
                    pluralS: false // Not needed, because units end with a S so it will automatically removed if the unit value is lower than 2
                }
            }
        });
```

**This is the error line:**

```
client.giveawaysManager.start(giveawayChannel, {
```

Answer (score 0):

In index.js:

```
const { GiveawaysManager } = require('discord-giveaways')

client.giveaways = new GiveawaysManager(client, {
        storage : './giveaways.json',
        updateCoundownEvery: 5000,
        embedColor: '#ff0000',
        reaction: ''
})
```

In giveaways.json:

```
[]
```